# How Would I Delete This Class Object? (C++)

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm working on a simple inheritance class right now to practice for a test, and I can't seem to figure out how to delete one of the objects. Code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Human
{
public:

void speakNicely();
void speakRudely();
int getAge();
void setAge(int x);
Human();
~Human();

private:

int age;
};

Human::Human(){}
Human::~Human(){}

void Human::speakNicely()
{
}

void Human::speakRudely()
{
}

void Human::setAge(int x)
{
    age = x;
}

int Human::getAge()
{
    return age;
}

////////////////////////////////////

class AlienObserver: public Human
{

public:
    AlienObserver();
    ~AlienObserver();
};

AlienObserver::AlienObserver(){}

AlienObserver::~AlienObserver(){}

int main()
{
    cout<<"TEST"<<endl;
    Human Todd;
    Todd.setAge(11);
    cout<<Todd.getAge()<<endl;
    Todd.speakNicely();
    Todd.speakRudely();
    AlienObserver Todderick;
    Todderick.setAge(15);
    cout<<Todderick.getAge()<<endl;
    Todderick.speakNicely();
    delete Todderick;  //problem line/////////////////////

return 0;
}
```

When I try and delete the Todderick object, I get an error that says the compiler was expecting a pointer. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: No `new()`, no `delete` needed at all??

Comment: Older textbooks may still start with `new/delete` but that's now rarely needed. Here, the `delete` is utterly unnecessary (no `new`) and that's common. And if you do need `new`, `std::unique_ptr` often takes care of the `delete` for you. And in the few remaining cases, there's also `std::shared_ptr`. It's been a while since I last needed `delete`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `delete` takes a pointer returned by `new` and destroys the object the pointer points to. More specifically, it does *only* that. Passing anything else but a pointer as described above (or a `nullptr`) to `delete` is undefined behavior.

Variables with automatic storage (such as `Todderick`) do not need to be destroyed manually, it happens automatically after the end of its lifetime (i.e. after the program flow exists the scope in which the variable was defined).

Answer (score 0):

[operator delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) takes a pointer as argument

```
void operator delete  ( void* ptr );
```

but you try to give it an object

```
AlienObserver Todderick;
```

This is wrong. You mustn't call delete on objects with automatic storage duration in C++. They will be deleted at the end of their scope, that is at the end of the area of their visibility in program.

```
{
    //...
    AlienObserver Todderick;
    Todderick.setAge(15);
    cout<<Todderick.getAge()<<endl;
    Todderick.speakNicely();
    //...
return 0;
}  // here Toderick is deleted automatically and it's 
   // destructor is called as well
```

Moreover every call to delete has to have matched previously made call to `new`. You call `delete` only on pointers received from a call to `new`. Lastly, it has to be always a call to appropriate form of `delete`.

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );  
-->  void operator delete  ( void* ptr );

void* operator new[]( std::size_t count );
-->  void operator delete [] ( void* ptr );
```